# iPhone touch is behaving like hover in HTML5 app

Tags: jquery, ios, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a HTML5 app with Bootstrap. I have some custom markup in order to skin some radio buttons, and some JQuery to drive it:

```
<div role="group" class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <label for="radioOption1" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" id="radioOption1" name="Options" />
        <span>ABC</span>
    </label>
    <label for="radioOption2" class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" id="radioOption2" name="Options" />
        <span>XYZ</span>
    </label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var radios = $("input[name=\"Options\"");
        radios.click(function () {
            radios.each(function () {
                $("label[for=\"" + $(this).attr("id") + "\"]").toggleClass("btn-primary", $(this).is(":checked"));
                $("label[for=\"" + $(this).attr("id") + "\"]").toggleClass("btn-default", !$(this).is(":checked"));
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works on desktop, but on my iPhone, whenever I tap one of the labels, it changes to display the hover styles for desktop, rather than the click styles.

So it appears that "touch" is equivalent to "hover" in this particular instance.

Does anyone have any experience of this or know how to fix it?

Comment: `var radios = $("input[name=\"Options\"");` syntax error or just a typo `]` closing is missing here.

Comment: Do you have a hover state set in your css for the radios?

Comment: @Jai it was the typo! Well done, and thank you! I guess desktop browsers are a little better at fixing these issues than mobile browsers are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var radios = $('input[name="Options"]');
    radios.change(function () {
        $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').toggleClass("btn-primary", $(this).is(":checked"))
           .siblings('label').toggleClass("btn-primary btn-default");
        });
    });
});
```